# Run function once then disallow further calls for 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop a function being fired again for 5 seconds after the last.

**This is what I had:**

```
return {
    buildUI: function() {
        el.nav.on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                el.logo.addClass('spin');
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                el.logo.removeClass('spin');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On mouseenter, add class to spin the logo. On mouseleave, remove the class. But to stop the logo spinning every mouseenter, I want to add a 5 second ban since the last.

**This is what I tried, amongst other attempts:**

```
var flipLogoTimer;
return {
    el.nav.on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            if (!flipLogoTimer) {
                el.logo.removeClass('spin').addClass('spin');
            }
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            el.logo.removeClass('spin');
            flipLogoTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                //
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to add a 5 second timer to the mouseleave event, so the next mouseenter can check if the timer is still running to determine whether or not to run the animation again.

Where am I going wrong and is there a better way? It's a difficult one to search for, as there are so many questions about running a function on a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flag like

```
return {
    buildUI: function () {
        var flag = false;
        el.nav.on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                if (flag) {
                    return;
                }
                el.logo.addClass('spin');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                if (flag) {
                    return;
                }
                flag = true;
                el.logo.removeClass('spin');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    flag = false;
                }, 5000)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this by toggling value of `flipLogoTimer`

```
var flipLogoTimer=false;
return {
    el.nav.on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            if (!flipLogoTimer) {
                el.logo.removeClass('spin').addClass('spin');
            }
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            el.logo.removeClass('spin');
            flipLogoTimer=true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                 flipLogoTimer=false;
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp. Idea: you fix last time when you added/removed class, and compare it with current date.

```
// 5000 - equal to 5 seconds
function checkTimestamp(a, b){
  return Math.abs(a - b) < 5000;
}
return {
    buildUI: function () {
        var lastTimeStamp = null;
        el.nav.on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                if(lastTimeStamp && checkTimestamp(lastTimeStamp, Date.now())
                  return false;
                el.logo.addClass('spin');
                lastTimeStamp = Date.now();
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                if(lastTimeStamp && checkTimestamp(lastTimeStamp, Date.now())
                  return false;
                el.logo.removeClass('spin');
                lastTimeStamp = Date.now();
            }
        });
    }
}
```